# Visual Basic Excel Function - Range Offset Error

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a function that will select a cell at an offset of `(1,1)` from the cell currently selected in Excel.

My subroutine is as follows:

```
Sub RangeOffset()
    Range(ActiveCell).Offset(RowOffSet:=1, ColumnOffset:=1).Select
End Sub
```

When I run the function I only get a window that displays "400" - I can't work out why the function does not work as intended. If I were to put in "A1" say instead of ActiveCell the function works perfectly - why?

Answer (score 4):

The **[Application.ActiveCell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834673.aspx)** property is a `Range` object, not a string literal.

You can either use it directly as such:

```
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1)
```

Or instead call its `Address` property to return a string literal.

```
Range(ActiveCell.Address).Offset(1,1)
```

The latter technique is clearly wasteful, although storing the address allows you to reset the user's active cell once your function is complete.